# Hypernym for increasing and decreasing

Tags: functions

I'm looking for a word that encompasses the words "increasing" and "decreasing," for the purposes of being able to say that "a function changes [that word]." I am specifically not looking for a word relating to the actions of increasing or decreasing something, but rather a function's state of being increasing or decreasing.

For example:
Being even or odd is parity
Being negative or positive is sign
Being concave up or concave down is concavity

So, being increasing or decreasing is [crease, perhaps]? As in, "the function f changes crease at x=0" instead of saying "the function f changes from increasing to decreasing at x=0."

Thanks!

Comment: Direction? Though there might be a few edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Monotonicity should be the word you're looking for:

For example, $f(x) = x^2 + 2x + 1$ changes monotonicity from (strictly) decreasing to (strictly) increasing at $x=-1$.

Comment: Please explain the downvote to me - how is this not accurate?

Comment: My understanding is that since a function is either monotonic (if it is either monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing) or not over a certain interval, you can't really ask what the motonicity is, only if it is monotonic or not.

Comment: Maybe the absolute change $f(x+d)-f(x)$ is more like what you‘re looking for then?